# ObjectIdentity.resolveWithMib() fails to resolve instance indices with InetAddressIPv4 type

Tags: pysnmp

While walking `TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionTable`, I noticed that their table indices were left unresolved after calling `resolveWithMib()`; turning MIB instrumentation debugging on revealed that the size constraint checks were applied to the textual IP address value, and not to the raw (4-byte) value.  The problem does not occur for non-IP-address table indices, such as `IF-MIB::ifIndex`.

To reproduce:

```
from pysnmp.smi.rfc1902 import ObjectIdentity
from pysnmp.smi.builder import MibBuilder
from pysnmp.smi.compiler import addMibCompiler
from pysnmp.smi.view import MibViewController
from pysnmp.debug import Debug, setLogger

builder = MibBuilder()
addMibCompiler(builder)
builder.loadModules('IF-MIB')
builder.loadModules('TCP-MIB')
view = MibViewController(builder)

def doit(*poargs):
    print(ObjectIdentity(*poargs).resolveWithMib(view).getMibSymbol())

setLogger(Debug('all'))
doit('.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1')
doit('.1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7.1.9.49.48.46.48.46.48.46.49.49.22.1.14.49.57.50.46.49.54.57.46.50.48.46.49.53.52.2629')
```

Returns:

```
2017-09-28 19:14:35,045 pysnmp: running pysnmp version 4.3.9
2017-09-28 19:14:35,045 pysnmp: debug category 'all' enabled
2017-09-28 19:14:35,045 pysnmp: resolving .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1 as OID or label
2017-09-28 19:14:35,046 pysnmp: indexMib: re-indexing MIB view
2017-09-28 19:14:35,049 pysnmp: getNodeNameByOid: resolved :1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1 -> ('iso', 'org', 'dod', 'internet', 'mgmt', 'mib-2', 'interfaces', 'ifTable', 'ifEntry', 'ifDescr').1
2017-09-28 19:14:35,049 pysnmp: resolved ('.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.1',) into prefix ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2') and suffix ObjectName('1')
2017-09-28 19:14:35,049 pysnmp: getNodeNameByOid: resolved :1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2 -> ('iso', 'org', 'dod', 'internet', 'mgmt', 'mib-2', 'interfaces', 'ifTable', 'ifEntry', 'ifDescr').()
2017-09-28 19:14:35,049 pysnmp: resolved prefix ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2') into MIB node MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), DisplayString(subtypeSpec=ConstraintsIntersection(ValueSizeConstraint(0, 65535), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255))))
2017-09-28 19:14:35,049 pysnmp: getNodeNameByOid: resolved :(1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1) -> ('iso', 'org', 'dod', 'internet', 'mgmt', 'mib-2', 'interfaces', 'ifTable', 'ifEntry').()
2017-09-28 19:14:35,049 pysnmp: resolved indices are (InterfaceIndex(1),)
('IF-MIB', 'ifDescr', (InterfaceIndex(1),))
2017-09-28 19:14:35,050 pysnmp: resolving .1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7.1.9.49.48.46.48.46.48.46.49.49.22.1.14.49.57.50.46.49.54.57.46.50.48.46.49.53.52.2629 as OID or label
2017-09-28 19:14:35,051 pysnmp: getNodeNameByOid: resolved :1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7.1.9.49.48.46.48.46.48.46.49.49.22.1.14.49.57.50.46.49.54.57.46.50.48.46.49.53.52.2629 -> ('iso', 'org', 'dod', 'internet', 'mgmt', 'mib-2', 'tcp', 'tcpConnectionTable', 'tcpConnectionEntry', 'tcpConnectionState').1.9.49.48.46.48.46.48.46.49.49.22.1.14.49.57.50.46.49.54.57.46.50.48.46.49.53.52.2629
2017-09-28 19:14:35,051 pysnmp: resolved ('.1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7.1.9.49.48.46.48.46.48.46.49.49.22.1.14.49.57.50.46.49.54.57.46.50.48.46.49.53.52.2629',) into prefix ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7') and suffix ObjectName('1.9.49.48.46.48.46.48.46.49.49.22.1.14.49.57.50.46.49.54.57.46.50.48.46.49.53.52.2629')
2017-09-28 19:14:35,051 pysnmp: getNodeNameByOid: resolved :1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7 -> ('iso', 'org', 'dod', 'internet', 'mgmt', 'mib-2', 'tcp', 'tcpConnectionTable', 'tcpConnectionEntry', 'tcpConnectionState').()
2017-09-28 19:14:35,051 pysnmp: resolved prefix ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7') into MIB node MibTableColumn((1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 6, 19, 1, 7), Integer32(subtypeSpec=ConstraintsIntersection(ValueRangeConstraint(-2147483648, 2147483647), ConstraintsUnion(SingleValueConstraint(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))), NamedValues((('synReceived', 4), ('established', 5), ('finWait2', 7), ('timeWait', 11), ('finWait1', 6), ('lastAck', 9), ('closeWait', 8), ('deleteTCB', 12), ('closed', 1), ('closing', 10), ('listen', 2), ('synSent', 3)))))
2017-09-28 19:14:35,051 pysnmp: getNodeNameByOid: resolved :(1, 3, 6, 1, 2, 1, 6, 19, 1) -> ('iso', 'org', 'dod', 'internet', 'mgmt', 'mib-2', 'tcp', 'tcpConnectionTable', 'tcpConnectionEntry').()
2017-09-28 19:14:35,052 pysnmp: error resolving table indices at MibTableRow, (9, 49, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 49, 49, 22, 1, 14, 49, 57, 50, 46, 49, 54, 57, 46, 50, 48, 46, 49, 53, 52, 2629): ConstraintsIntersection(ValueSizeConstraint(0, 65535), ValueSizeConstraint(4, 4)) failed at: ValueConstraintError("ValueSizeConstraint(4, 4) failed at: ValueConstraintError('10.0.0.11',)",) at InetAddressIPv4
2017-09-28 19:14:35,052 pysnmp: resolved indices are ((9, 49, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 49, 49, 22, 1, 14, 49, 57, 50, 46, 49, 54, 57, 46, 50, 48, 46, 49, 53, 52, 2629),)
('TCP-MIB', 'tcpConnectionState', ((9, 49, 48, 46, 48, 46, 48, 46, 49, 49, 22, 1, 14, 49, 57, 50, 46, 49, 54, 57, 46, 50, 48, 46, 49, 53, 52, 2629),))
```

Note how `IF-MIB::ifDescr`'s instance index was resolved correctly to `(InterfaceIndex(1),)` while `TCP-MIB::tcpConnectionState`'s instance index was left unresolved as `((9, 49, 48, 46, ...),)`.

How can I fix or work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are passing malformed index. For example, the `46` ASCII ordinal represents decimal dot in IPv4 dotted notation. This dot should never be encoded into the OID.

Here is index structure for `tcpConnectionTable`:

```
INDEX   { tcpConnectionLocalAddressType,
          tcpConnectionLocalAddress,
          tcpConnectionLocalPort,
          tcpConnectionRemAddressType,
          tcpConnectionRemAddress,
          tcpConnectionRemPort }
```

All these components should end up in any valid index. If I take your reproducer and attempt the reverse transformation e.g. from symbolic indices (which is easy to build by hand) into OIDs and back:

```
oid = ObjectIdentity('TCP-MIB', 'tcpConnectionState', 
                     'ipv4', '10.0.0.11', 22,
                     'ipv4', '10.0.0.11', 1024).resolveWithMib(view)
print(oid)
mib_obj = ObjectIdentity(oid).resolveWithMib(view)
print(mib_obj.getMibSymbol())
```

I could see how the indices get encoded into OID and prove thay pysnmp can decode them back:

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.6.19.1.7.1.4.10.0.0.11.22.1.4.10.0.0.11.1024
('TCP-MIB', 'tcpConnectionState', 
 (InetAddressType('ipv4'), InetAddressIPv4(hexValue='0a00000b'), InetPortNumber(22),
  InetAddressType('ipv4'), InetAddressIPv4(hexValue='0a00000b'), InetPortNumber(1024)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I agree that the OID itself is malformed.  Since it is taken from Net-SNMP, I will redirect the question there.

Comment: Meanwhile, is there any way to insert a programmable hook so as to transform OIDs retrieved from the request before they are passed to the resolver view of the SNMPEngine instance, in order to deal with such malformed OIDs returned by the agent?